# How can i use different status page in MVC .net core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

My system has a website, a dashboard with an one admin.Users are redirected to statuspage during the visit in the same way as the admin, but I want the admin and users to see different pages

I am using this code but it's only work for both side..

app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/Error", "?code={0}"); // status page

project at github : https://github.com/ekremgunes/PortfolioProject

Comment: Could you please description more details about your question? Do you mean you want to let the exception to go to different page?

Comment: Yes sir.My system has a website, a dashboard with an one admin.Users are redirected to statuspage during the visit in the same way as the admin, but I want the admin and users to see different pages ui. i can post the project link here in a moment if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would use in the method of your controller:

```
if (User.IsInRole("Admin")) {
  return View(model);
} else {
  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage");
}
```

Comment: looking good but we have one user and no role , i will put project source link can you check it ?

Comment: @EkremGüneş Yes please add at least the Controller method where you are gonna return the view.
Are you sure that you can't use the global User object? You application has no login?

Comment: project at github : [PROJECT GİTHUB LİNK](https://github.com/ekremgunes/PortfolioProject) , here sir.